# BeautifulSoup - Scrape product and product variants and export it to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this [website](https://www.petbarn.com.au/dogs/dog-food/dry-dog-food) products listing what I am trying to achieve here is grab all the info per product for example: product_name, price and their variants info as well like 10kg, 20kg, 3kg and their prices accordingly. I have search the html they don't provide all the info I am looking for but under script tag they have a json residing which could be useful. Here is the json script tag:

```
</script><script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=swatch-option-111105]": {
                "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer": {
                    "selectorProduct": ".product-item-details",
                    "onlySwatches": true,
                    "enableControlLabel": false,
                    "numberToShow": 16,
                    "jsonConfig": {"attributes":{"1299":{"id":"1299","code":"size","label":"Size","options":[{"id":"6651","label":"10kg","products":["116724"]},{"id":"6780","label":"20kg","products":["108981"]},{"id":"6234","label":"3kg","products":["108987"]}],"position":"0"}},"template":"$<%- data.price %>","currencyFormat":"$%s","optionPrices":{"108987":{"baseOldPrice":{"amount":49.990908090909},"oldPrice":{"amount":54.99},"basePrice":{"amount":42.718180818182},"finalPrice":{"amount":46.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":0}},"108981":{"baseOldPrice":{"amount":172.71818081818},"oldPrice":{"amount":189.99},"basePrice":{"amount":128.17272627273},"finalPrice":{"amount":140.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":0}},"116724":{"baseOldPrice":{"amount":120.899999},"oldPrice":{"amount":132.99},"basePrice":{"amount":102.71818081818},"finalPrice":{"amount":112.99},"tierPrices":[],"msrpPrice":{"amount":0}}},"priceFormat":{"pattern":"$%s","precision":2,"requiredPrecision":2,"decimalSymbol":".","groupSymbol":",","groupLength":3,"integerRequired":false},"prices":{"baseOldPrice":{"amount":49.990908090909},"oldPrice":{"amount":54.99},"basePrice":{"amount":172.71818081818},"finalPrice":{"amount":189.99}},"productId":"111105","chooseText":"Choose an Option...","images":[],"index":{"108987":{"1299":"6234"},"108981":{"1299":"6780"},"116724":{"1299":"6651"}},"preSelectedGallery":[],"channel":"website","salesChannelCode":"base","sku":{"108987":"127956","108981":"127960","116724":"501600"},"labels":{"108987":{"sales_flag_label":"Great low price"},"108981":{"sales_flag_label":"Great low price"},"116724":{"sales_flag_label":"Great low price"}},"hasEndDate":{"108987":false,"108981":false,"116724":false},"dynamic":{"name":{"108987":{"value":"Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food - 3kg"},"108981":{"value":"Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food - 20kg"},"116724":{"value":"Black Hawk Fish & Potato Dog Food 10kg"}},"sku":{"108987":{"value":"127956"},"108981":{"value":"127960"},"116724":{"value":"501600"}},"gtin":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"marketing_offer_short":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"advice_care":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"product_category":{"108987":{"value":"Dry Food"},"108981":{"value":"Dry Food"},"116724":{"value":"Dry Food"}},"benefits":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"feeding_guide":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"health_condition_dietary":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"brand_filter":{"108987":{"value":"Black Hawk"},"108981":{"value":"Black Hawk"},"116724":{"value":"Black Hawk"}},"ingredients":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"activity_level":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"size":{"108987":{"value":"3kg"},"108981":{"value":"20kg"},"116724":{"value":"10kg"}},"food_type":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"health_benefits":{"108987":{"value":"Total Wellbeing"},"108981":{"value":"Total Wellbeing"},"116724":{"value":"Total Wellbeing"}},"life_stage":{"108987":{"value":"Adult"},"108981":{"value":"Adult"},"116724":{"value":"Adult"}},"flavour":{"108987":{"value":"Fish"},"108981":{"value":"Fish"},"116724":{"value":"Fish"}},"nutritional_info":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"breed":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"nutritional_info_table":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"australia_made":{"108987":{"value":"No"},"108981":{"value":"No"},"116724":{"value":"No"}},"nutrition_grade":{"108987":{"value":"Premium"},"108981":{"value":"Premium"},"116724":{"value":"Premium"}},"lifestyle":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"weight_control":{"108987":{"value":"No"},"108981":{"value":"No"},"116724":{"value":"No"}},"frequent_feeder_price":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}},"size_swatches":{"108987":{"value":""},"108981":{"value":""},"116724":{"value":""}}}},
                    "jsonSwatchConfig": {"1299":{"6651":{"type":"0","value":null,"label":"10kg"},"6780":{"type":"0","value":null,"label":"20kg"},"6234":{"type":"0","value":null,"label":"3kg"},"additional_data":"{\"update_product_preview_image\":\"1\",\"use_product_image_for_swatch\":0,\"text_swatch_as_multiple_select\":\"1\",\"swatch_input_type\":\"text\"}"}},
                    "mediaCallback": "https\u003A\u002F\u002Fwww.petbarn.com.au\u002Fswatches\u002Fajax\u002Fmedia\u002F",
                    "jsonSwatchImageSizeConfig": {"swatchImage":{"width":30,"height":20},"swatchThumb":{"height":90,"width":110}},
                    "showTooltip": 1                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I have manage to parse that script tag and turned that into python dictionary via json.loads() but couldn't figure out the best way to extract info and export it to csv. here is my code so far:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

now = datetime.now()
today = date.today()


class PetBarnProdScraper:

    all_info = []

    def fetch(self, url):
        print(f"HTTP GET request to URL: {url}", end="")
        res = requests.get(url)
        print(f" | Status Code: {res.status_code}")

        return res

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        product_urls = [a.get("href") for a in soup.select("a.product-item-link")]
        product_ids = [
            pid.get("id").split("-")[-1] for pid in soup.select("div.product-item-info")
        ]
        titles = [
            a.text.replace("\n", "").strip() for a in soup.select("a.product-item-link")
        ]
        old_price = [
            p.select_one("span.price").text for p in soup.select("span.old-price")
        ]
        ratings = [r.get("title") for r in soup.select("div.rating-result")]
        no_of_reviews = [review.text for review in soup.select("a.action.view")]
        data = (
            soup.select('script[type="text/x-magento-init"]')[3]
            .text.replace("\n", "")
            .strip()
        )
        data_json = json.loads(data)
        data_j = json.loads(
            data_json["*"]["Overdose_AdobeAnalytics/js/view/datalayer"]["datalayer"][0]
        )

        for idx in range(len(titles)):
            try:
                ratings_count = ratings[idx]
                reviews_count = no_of_reviews[idx]
                last_price = old_price[idx]
            except:
                ratings_count = "N/A"
                reviews_count = "N/A"
                last_price = "N/A"
            d = {
                "Scraped_Date": now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S").split(",")[0],
                "Scraped_Time": now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S").split(",")[1],
                "product_name": titles[idx],
                "price": data_j["PLP"]["products"][idx]["productPrice"],
                "old_price": last_price,
                "ratings": ratings_count,
                "number_of_reviews": reviews_count,
                "productSKU": data_j["PLP"]["products"][idx]["productSKU"],
                "productSize": data_j["PLP"]["products"][idx]["productSize"],
                "priceWithoutTax": data_j["PLP"]["products"][idx][
                    "productPriceLessTax"
                ],
                "lifeStage": data_j["PLP"]["products"][idx]["lifeStage"],
            }

            for prod_id in product_ids:
                details = soup.select_one(
                    f"script:-soup-contains('[data-role=swatch-option-{prod_id}]')"
                )
                labels = []
                if details:
                    json_details = json.loads(details.text.replace("\n", "").strip())
                    json_endpoint = json_details[f"[data-role=swatch-option-{prod_id}]"]
                    label_option_list = json_endpoint[
                        "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer"
                    ]["jsonConfig"]["attributes"]["1299"]["options"]
                    for lab in label_option_list:
                        labels.append(lab["label"])

                        d["label_options"] = labels
            print(d)
            self.all_info.append(d)

    def to_csv(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(self.all_info).fillna("")

        df.to_csv(f"{today}_petbarn.csv", index=False)

        print('Stored results to "petbarn.csv"')

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 2):  # total_number of pages
            url = f"https://www.petbarn.com.au/dogs/dog-food/dry-dog-food?p={i}"

            response = self.fetch(url)

            self.parse(response)

        self.to_csv()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper = PetBarnProdScraper()
    scraper.run()
```

every time I run that code the label_options column has always the same values which is the last one I am guessing. here is the output I am getting:

```
Scraped_Date,Scraped_Time,product_name,price,old_price,ratings,number_of_reviews,productSKU,productSize,priceWithoutTax,lifeStage,label_options
11/21/2022, 00:31:47,Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food,189.99,N/A,N/A,N/A,black-hawk-fish-&-potato-adult-dog-food,,172.72,Adult,"['10kg', '20kg', '3kg']"
11/21/2022, 00:31:47,SavourLife Ancient Grains Lean Chicken Adult Dog Food,159.99,N/A,N/A,N/A,savourlife-ancient-grains-lean-chicken-adult-dog-food,,145.45,Adult,"['10kg', '20kg', '3kg']"
```

Expected output:

```
Scraped_Date,Scraped_Time,product_name,price,old_price,ratings,number_of_reviews,productSKU,productSize,priceWithoutTax,lifeStage,label_options
11/21/2022, 00:31:47,Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food,189.99,N/A,N/A,N/A,black-hawk-fish-&-potato-adult-dog-food,,172.72,Adult,10kg
11/21/2022, 00:31:47,Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food,189.99,N/A,N/A,N/A,black-hawk-fish-&-potato-adult-dog-food,,172.72,Adult,20kg
11/21/2022, 00:31:47,Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food,189.99,N/A,N/A,N/A,black-hawk-fish-&-potato-adult-dog-food,,172.72,Adult,3kg
11/21/2022, 00:31:47,SavourLife Ancient Grains Lean Chicken Adult Dog Food,159.99,N/A,N/A,N/A,savourlife-ancient-grains-lean-chicken-adult-dog-food,,145.45,Adult,3kg
11/21/2022, 00:31:47,SavourLife Ancient Grains Lean Chicken Adult Dog Food,159.99,N/A,N/A,N/A,savourlife-ancient-grains-lean-chicken-adult-dog-food,,145.45,Adult,20kg
```

Can anyone help me figure out the best way to get the expected output? Thanks!

UPDATE:
Updated the code based on Driftr95' answer:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

now = datetime.now()
today = date.today()


class PetBarnProdScraper:

    all_info = []

    def fetch(self, url):
        print(f"HTTP GET request to URL: {url}", end="")
        res = requests.get(url)
        print(f" | Status Code: {res.status_code}")

        return res

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        product_urls = [a.get("href") for a in soup.select("a.product-item-link")]
        product_ids = [
            pid.get("id").split("-")[-1] for pid in soup.select("div.product-item-info")
        ]
        titles = [
            a.text.replace("\n", "").strip() for a in soup.select("a.product-item-link")
        ]
        old_price = [
            p.select_one("span.price").text for p in soup.select("span.old-price")
        ]
        ratings = [r.get("title") for r in soup.select("div.rating-result")]
        no_of_reviews = [review.text for review in soup.select("a.action.view")]
        data = (
            soup.select('script[type="text/x-magento-init"]')[3]
            .text.replace("\n", "")
            .strip()
        )
        data_json = json.loads(data)
        data_j = json.loads(
            data_json["*"]["Overdose_AdobeAnalytics/js/view/datalayer"]["datalayer"][0]
        )

        for idx in range(len(titles)):
            try:
                ratings_count = ratings[idx]
                reviews_count = no_of_reviews[idx]
                last_price = old_price[idx]
            except:
                ratings_count = "N/A"
                reviews_count = "N/A"
                last_price = "N/A"
            d = {
                "Scraped_Date": now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S").split(",")[0],
                "Scraped_Time": now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S").split(",")[1],
                "product_name": titles[idx],
                "price": data_j["PLP"]["products"][idx]["productPrice"],
                "old_price": last_price,
                "ratings": ratings_count,
                "number_of_reviews": reviews_count,
                "productSKU": data_j["PLP"]["products"][idx]["productSKU"],
                "productSize": data_j["PLP"]["products"][idx]["productSize"],
                "priceWithoutTax": data_j["PLP"]["products"][idx][
                    "productPriceLessTax"
                ],
                "lifeStage": data_j["PLP"]["products"][idx]["lifeStage"],
            }

            for prod_id in product_ids:
                details = soup.select_one(
                    f"script:-soup-contains('[data-role=swatch-option-{prod_id}]')"
                )
                if details:
                    json_details = json.loads(details.text.replace("\n", "").strip())
                    dataJC = json_details[f"[data-role=swatch-option-{prod_id}]"][
                        "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer"
                    ]["jsonConfig"]
                    productId = dataJC["productId"]
                    jcInfs = [
                        {
                            "productId": productId,
                            "optionKey": k,
                            "sku": "?",
                            "index": v["1299"] if "1299" in v else None,
                        }
                        for k, v in dataJC["index"].items()
                    ]
                    orInfs = [
                        ("optionPrices", "amount", "reverseNest"),
                        ("dynamic", "value", "nest1"),
                        ("labels", "", "reverseNest"),
                        ("hasEndDate", "", "noNesting"),
                    ]
                    relevInfs = []
                    for kk, vk, nt in orInfs:
                        if kk not in dataJC:
                            continue
                        if nt == "noNesting":
                            relevInfs += [(kk, vk, dataJC[kk])]
                            continue
                        if nt == "nest1":
                            relevInfs += [(kk, vk, vd) for kk, vd in dataJC[kk].items()]
                            continue
                        if nt != "reverseNest":
                            ## can put a default action here
                            continue
                        ## nt == 'reverseNest'
                        orInf = {}
                        for pk, po in dataJC[kk].items():
                            for kpo, vpo in po.items():
                                if kpo not in orInf:
                                    orInf[kpo] = {}
                                orInf[kpo][pk] = vpo

                        relevInfs += [(kk, vk, vi) for kk, vi in orInf.items()]

                    for i, j in enumerate(jcInfs):
                        for kk, vk, vd in relevInfs:
                            if j["optionKey"] not in vd:
                                continue
                            relevInf = vd[j["optionKey"]]
                            if type(relevInf) != dict:
                                j[kk] = relevInf
                            elif vk in relevInf and relevInf[vk]:
                                j[kk] = relevInf[vk]
                        # combine with main variation
                        jcInfs[i] = {
                            k: v
                            for k, v in (
                                list(d.items())
                                + [(jk, jv) for jk, jv in j.items() if jk not in d]
                            )
                        }
                    for j in jcInfs:
                        self.all_info.append(j)
            self.all_info.append(d)

    def to_csv(self):

        df = pd.DataFrame(self.all_info).fillna("")

        df.to_csv(f"{today}_petbarn.csv", index=False)

        print('Stored results to "petbarn.csv"')

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 2):  # total_number of pages
            url = f"https://www.petbarn.com.au/dogs/dog-food/dry-dog-food?p={i}"

            response = self.fetch(url)

            self.parse(response)

        self.to_csv()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper = PetBarnProdScraper()
    scraper.run()
```

the code and output matches the expectation but not paired up instead product_name rows keep repeating itself where on the other hand name column have just 3 rows so it'd be great to have those rows intact with each other.
Here is the output:

```
Scraped_Date,Scraped_Time,product_name,price,old_price,ratings,number_of_reviews,productSKU,productSize,priceWithoutTax,lifeStage,productId,optionKey,sku,index,baseOldPrice,oldPrice,basePrice,finalPrice,tierPrices,name,product_category,brand_filter,size,health_benefits,life_stage,flavour,australia_made,nutrition_grade,weight_control,on_sale,hasEndDate,breed,new,marketing_offer_short,sales_flag_label,activity_level
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,111105,108987,127956,6234,49.990908090909,54.99,42.718180818182,46.99,[],Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food - 3kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,3kg,Total Wellbeing,Adult,Fish,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,,,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,111105,108981,127960,6780,172.71818081818,189.99,128.17272627273,140.99,[],Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food - 20kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,20kg,Total Wellbeing,Adult,Fish,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,,,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,111105,116724,501600,6651,120.899999,132.99,102.71818081818,112.99,[],Black Hawk Fish & Potato Dog Food 10kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,10kg,Total Wellbeing,Adult,Fish,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,,,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,145209,143157,140846,6234,41.809089909091,45.99,41.809089909091,45.99,[],SavourLife Ancient Grains Lean Chicken Adult Dog Food 3kg,Dry Food,SavourLife Ancient Grains,3kg,Weight Management,Adult,Chicken,No,Essential,Yes,Sale,False,All,New,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,145209,143163,140847,6780,145.44545354545,159.99,99.090908090909,109.0,[],SavourLife Ancient Grains Lean Chicken Adult Dog Food 20kg,Dry Food,SavourLife Ancient Grains,20kg,Weight Management,Adult,Chicken,No,Essential,Yes,,False,All,New,Only $109,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,144663,142980,141739,6234,48.172726272727,52.99,39.990908090909,43.99,[],Black Hawk Chicken & Rice Medium Puppy Food 3kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,3kg,Healthy Development,Puppy,Chicken,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,Medium,,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,144663,142983,141740,6651,114.53636263636,125.99,101.80908990909,111.99,[],Black Hawk Chicken & Rice Medium Puppy Food 10kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,10kg,,Puppy,Chicken,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,Medium,,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,144663,142959,141741,6780,169.99090809091,186.99,135.99090809091,149.59,[],Black Hawk Chicken & Rice Medium Puppy Food 20kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,20kg,,Puppy,Chicken,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,Medium,,20% off,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,144600,144351,141490,7815,36.354544454545,39.99,30.899999,33.99,[],ProBalance Care Joint Care Adult Dog Dry Food 2.5kg,Dry Food,ProBalance,2.5kg,Hip and Joint Support,Adult,,No,Superior,No,,False,,,,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,144600,144009,141491,17823,117.26363536364,128.99,93.809089909091,103.19,[],ProBalance Care Joint Care Adult Dog Dry Food 12kg,Dry Food,ProBalance,12kg,Hip and Joint Support,Adult,,No,Superior,No,,False,,,20% off,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,113391,63624,30318,6687,173.62727172727,190.99,115.03636263636,126.54,[],Royal Canin Maxi Puppy Dog Food 15kg,Dry Food,ROYAL CANIN,15kg,Growth Support,Puppy,Chicken,No,Superior,No,,False,"Giant, Large",,,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,113391,63111,29321,84219,64.536362636364,70.99,51.809089909091,56.99,[],Royal Canin Maxi Puppy Dog Food 4kg,Dry Food,ROYAL CANIN,4kg,Growth Support,Puppy,Chicken,No,Superior,No,,False,Large,,Buy 2 for $106.49,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,113391,123852,140248,8373,20.899999,22.99,17.763635363636,19.54,[],Royal Canin Maxi Breed Puppy Food 1kg,Dry Food,ROYAL CANIN,1kg,Healthy Development,Puppy,Chicken,No,Superior,No,,False,Large,,Buy 2 for $34.49,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,145119,143145,140840,7815,45.445453545455,49.99,45.445453545455,49.99,[],SavourLife Grain Free Sensitive OFish Adult Dog Food 2.5kg,Dry Food,SavourLife,2.5kg,"Grain Free, Sensitive Skin, Sensitive Stomach",Adult,Fish,No,Superior,No,Sale,False,All,New,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,145119,143148,140841,6651,113.62727172727,124.99,113.62727172727,124.99,[],SavourLife Grain Free Sensitive OFish Adult Dog Food 10kg,Dry Food,SavourLife,10kg,"Grain Free, Sensitive Skin, Sensitive Stomach",Adult,Fish,No,Superior,No,Sale,False,All,New,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,144657,142974,141735,6651,114.53636263636,125.99,99.990908090909,109.99,[],Black Hawk Lamb & Rice Large Puppy Food 10kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,10kg,Healthy Development,Puppy,Lamb,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,Large,,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,144657,142953,141736,6780,169.99090809091,186.99,135.99090809091,149.59,[],Black Hawk Lamb & Rice Large Puppy Food 20kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,20kg,,Puppy,Lamb,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,Large,,20% off,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,112734,62448,29328,6234,49.081817181818,53.99,36.118180818182,39.73,[],Royal Canin Labrador Dog Food 3kg,Dry Food,ROYAL CANIN,3kg,,"Adult, Senior",Chicken,No,Superior,No,,False,Labrador Retriever,,,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,112734,62985,30327,17823,148.17272627273,162.99,92.718180818182,101.99,[],Royal Canin Labrador Dog Food 12kg,Dry Food,ROYAL CANIN,12kg,,"Adult, Senior",Chicken,No,Superior,No,,False,Labrador Retriever,,,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,172479,128169,140460,8514,45.445453545455,49.99,40.899999,44.99,[],Acana Light & Fit Dry Dog Food 2kg,Dry Food,Acana,2kg,Weight Management,Adult,Chicken,No,Superior,No,,False,,,,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,172479,128175,140469,292890,159.08181718182,174.99,149.99090809091,164.99,[],Acana Light & Fit Dry Dog Food 11.3kg,Dry Food,Acana,11.3kg,Weight Management,Adult,Chicken,No,Superior,No,,False,,,,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,145083,143316,140842,7815,43.627271727273,47.99,43.627271727273,47.99,[],SavourLife Grain Free Chicken 7+ Senior Dog Food 2.5kg,Dry Food,SavourLife,2.5kg,"Ageing, Grain Free",Senior,Chicken,No,Superior,No,Sale,False,All,New,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,145083,143322,140843,6651,109.08181718182,119.99,109.08181718182,119.99,[],SavourLife Grain Free Chicken 7+ Senior Dog Food 10kg,Dry Food,SavourLife,10kg,"Ageing, Grain Free",Senior,Chicken,No,Superior,No,Sale,False,All,New,,,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,144618,144387,141488,7815,38.172726272727,41.99,32.445453545455,35.69,[],ProBalance Care Sensitive Skin Adult Dog Dry Food 2.5kg,Dry Food,ProBalance,2.5kg,Sensitive Skin,Adult,,No,Superior,No,,False,,,,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,144618,144021,141489,17823,118.17272627273,129.99,94.536362636364,103.99,[],ProBalance Care Sensitive Skin Adult Dog Dry Food 12kg,Dry Food,ProBalance,12kg,Sensitive Skin,Adult,,No,Superior,No,,False,,,20% off,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,172476,128235,140423,8514,54.536362636364,59.99,51.809089909091,56.99,[],Orijen Six Fish Dry Dog Food 2kg,Dry Food,Orijen,2kg,Grain Free,Adult,Fish,No,Superior,No,,False,,,,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,172476,128214,140431,2825802,190.899999,209.99,181.80908990909,199.99,[],Orijen Six Fish Dry Dog Food 11.4kg,Dry Food,Orijen,11.4kg,Grain Free,Adult,Fish,No,Superior,No,,False,,,,Great low price,
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,115260,109329,127959,6780,156.35454445455,171.99,119.99090809091,131.99,[],Black Hawk Lamb And Rice Adult Dog Food - 20kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,20kg,,Adult,Lamb,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,,,,,High Activity
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,115260,109323,127955,6234,46.354544454545,50.99,28.172726272727,30.99,[],Black Hawk Lamb And Rice Adult Dog Food - 3kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,3kg,,Adult,Lamb,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,,,3kg bags for $30.99,,High Activity
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,115260,109317,501601,6651,110.899999,121.99,93.627271727273,102.99,[],Black Hawk Lamb & Rice Adult Dog Food 10kg,Dry Food,Black Hawk,10kg,,Adult,Lamb,No,Premium,No,Sale,True,,,,,High Activity
11/21/2022, 14:34:56,Advance Oodles Puppy Food 2.5kg,40.77,$47.99,100%,1,143138,,37.06,Puppy,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every time I run that code the label_options column has always the same values which is the last one I am guessing

Are you sure that they don't just all happen to have the same set of options? It *shouldn't* be repeating since you're clearing the list with `labels = []` in the loop - although you can just append `label_options` *outside* the `for lab...` loop:

```py
                    for lab in label_option_list:
                        labels.append(lab["label"])

                    d["label_options"] = labels
```

instead of updating it for every label in `label_option_list`.

---

---

Anyway, I think your main issue is on the part where you want separate rows for each variant, and I *can* help a bit there.

> Can anyone help me figure out the best way to get the expected output

I don't know if this is the *best* way, but this how I would get the maximum amount of information from the JSON in the script:

---

For this example, I copied the JSON inside the `script` tag from the html snippet in your question (to a variable `pasted_jstr`) as well as some of your output to set `d` and `dataJC` with

```py
dataj = json.loads(pasted_jstr)
dataJC = dataj['[data-role=swatch-option-111105]']['Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer']['jsonConfig']

# from io import StringIO
csvStr = '''
Scraped_Date,Scraped_Time,product_name,price,old_price,ratings,number_of_reviews,productSKU,productSize,priceWithoutTax,lifeStage,label_options
11/21/2022, 00:31:47,Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food,189.99,N/A,N/A,N/A,black-hawk-fish-&-potato-adult-dog-food,,172.72,Adult,"['10kg', '20kg', '3kg']"
'''.split('\n')
d = dict(zip(csvStr[1].split(',')[:-1], csvStr[2].split(',')))
```

---

and then

```py
productId = dataJC['productId']
jcInfs = [{
    'productId': productId, 'optionKey': k, 'sku': '?',
    'index': v['1299'] if '1299' in v else None
} for k, v in dataJC['index'].items()] 
orInfs = [
    ('optionPrices', 'amount', 'reverseNest'), 
    ('dynamic', 'value', 'nest1'),
    ('labels', '', 'reverseNest'),
    ('hasEndDate', '', 'noNesting')
]
relevInfs = []
for kk, vk, nt in orInfs:
    if kk not in dataJC: continue
    if nt == 'noNesting':
        relevInfs += [(kk, vk, dataJC[kk])]
        continue
    
    if nt == 'nest1':
        relevInfs += [(kk, vk, vd) for kk, vd in dataJC[kk].items()]
        continue
    
    if nt != 'reverseNest':
        ## can put a default action here
        continue
    
    ## nt == 'reverseNest'
    orInf = {}
    for pk, po in dataJC[kk].items():
        for kpo, vpo in po.items():
            if kpo not in orInf: orInf[kpo] = {}
            orInf[kpo][pk] = vpo
    relevInfs += [(kk, vk, vi) for kk, vi in orInf.items()]
    
for i, j in enumerate(jcInfs):
    for kk, vk, vd in relevInfs:
        if j['optionKey'] not in vd: continue
        relevInf = vd[j['optionKey']]
        if type(relevInf) != dict: j[kk] = relevInf
        elif vk in relevInf and relevInf[vk]: j[kk] = relevInf[vk]
    
    # combine with main variation
    jcInfs[i] = {k:v for k, v in (list(d.items()) + [
        (jk, jv) for jk, jv in j.items() if jk not in d
    ])}
```

You can set `orInfs` somewhere outside the loops and add in any keys [with which you want to get info from the json], and you can also add the actions for new formats/`nt` ("nesting type") into the `for kk, vk, nt in orInfs` loop. (You can also separate the loop out into its own function...)

<sub>I was able to print the table below with `print(pd.DataFrame(jcInfs).to_markdown(index=False))`</sub>

```
| Scraped_Date   | Scraped_Time   | product_name                              |   price | old_price   | ratings   | number_of_reviews   | productSKU                              | productSize   |   priceWithoutTax | lifeStage   |   productId |   optionKey |    sku |   index |   baseOldPrice |   oldPrice |   basePrice |   finalPrice | tierPrices   | name                                             | product_category   | brand_filter   | size   | health_benefits   | life_stage   | flavour   | australia_made   | nutrition_grade   | weight_control   | sales_flag_label   | hasEndDate   |
|:---------------|:---------------|:------------------------------------------|--------:|:------------|:----------|:--------------------|:----------------------------------------|:--------------|------------------:|:------------|------------:|------------:|-------:|--------:|---------------:|-----------:|------------:|-------------:|:-------------|:-------------------------------------------------|:-------------------|:---------------|:-------|:------------------|:-------------|:----------|:-----------------|:------------------|:-----------------|:-------------------|:-------------|
| 11/21/2022     | 00:31:47       | Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food |  189.99 | N/A         | N/A       | N/A                 | black-hawk-fish-&-potato-adult-dog-food |               |            172.72 | Adult       |      111105 |      108987 | 127956 |    6234 |        49.9909 |      54.99 |     42.7182 |        46.99 | []           | Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food - 3kg  | Dry Food           | Black Hawk     | 3kg    | Total Wellbeing   | Adult        | Fish      | No               | Premium           | No               | Great low price    | False        |
| 11/21/2022     | 00:31:47       | Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food |  189.99 | N/A         | N/A       | N/A                 | black-hawk-fish-&-potato-adult-dog-food |               |            172.72 | Adult       |      111105 |      108981 | 127960 |    6780 |       172.718  |     189.99 |    128.173  |       140.99 | []           | Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food - 20kg | Dry Food           | Black Hawk     | 20kg   | Total Wellbeing   | Adult        | Fish      | No               | Premium           | No               | Great low price    | False        |
| 11/21/2022     | 00:31:47       | Black Hawk Fish And Potato Adult Dog Food |  189.99 | N/A         | N/A       | N/A                 | black-hawk-fish-&-potato-adult-dog-food |               |            172.72 | Adult       |      111105 |      116724 | 501600 |    6651 |       120.9    |     132.99 |    102.718  |       112.99 | []           | Black Hawk Fish & Potato Dog Food 10kg           | Dry Food           | Black Hawk     | 10kg   | Total Wellbeing   | Adult        | Fish      | No               | Premium           | No               | Great low price    | False        |
```

Comment: @Drfitr95 I tried your approach and it matches the expected output but it is only fetching one single product not all of them. I have update the question with the code I tried with your approach. Can you please look into this? Thank you!

Comment: @X-somtheing sorry I forgot to mention the last part of incorporating my solution into your code. You still need to add to `all_info`, but `jcInfs` is the like the new `d` - it's multiple rows though, so you can add instead of appending; where you had `self.all_info.append(d)`, you should now have **`self.all_info += jcInfs`** (*although you can also do `for j in jcInfs: self.all_info.append(j)` instead*). I hope it works now. Please let me know

Comment: @X-somtheing Btw, you can still save with `pd.DataFrame(self.all_info).fillna("").to_csv(f"{today}_petbarn.csv", index=False)` but it should be *outside* of all the loops, at the end of `parse()` - or even in just save *`scraper.all_info`* at the end of *`__main__`*. It's just important to remember that `jcInfs` only contains *all the variants of **one** product*, and `all_info` is what should have all the products [with the current code at least]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for the explanation. There is still one issue with main dixtionary `d` and primary dictionary `jcInfs` they are not intacted with each othe for example `product_name` rows keeps repeating where `name` rows which is coming from `jcInfs` only have 3 rows. And I am looking to have `product_name` rows repeat per variation. Any chance we can achieve that?

Comment: I have updated the code above with `for j in jcInfs: self.all_info.append(j)`

Comment: I figured it out why product_name rows were repeating I forgot I was running it under the loop `for idx in range(len(titles)):` removed the loop and it is working fine but now question is how to get those products which do not have variations it will be better to have a separate question for this.

Comment: @X-somtheing `self.all_info.append(d)` should take care of the ones without variants - [here's a version with my corrections](https://pastebin.com/eH2wmF7X) (all my changes are marked with `#!#`; as it is, the products with variants will have one extra row from `d` as it is before adding variants, but the version without the extra row is in comment)

Comment: @X-somtheing If you're interested, I also had [some suggested changes](https://pastebin.com/pN3GGzEe) beyond the corrections; the way you're doing it is actually a bit dangerous - it will raise an exception if any of the html elements are missing, and also, they might not line up perfectly, especially the ratings, reviews and lastprice, so it's better to find the container element (from which you're already getting `product_ids`), and then search for each product detail within that container element

Comment: ( If you want to discuss further, we can [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249784/discussion-between-driftr95-and-x-somtheing). )

Comment: Amazing! I really like your suggestions in my code and I am going to keep that one it is really cool and beyond my expectations. Appreciate your efforts and thank you so much for putting your time into this really appreciated!

Comment: I have a another question regarding scraping this website https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190026/beautifulsoup-scrape-product-and-product-price-per-variants-json-parsing-and-e . Please if you have some time can you take a look at it?